# Selenium Webdriver unable to locate element from webtable

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access a webtable which is quite static and get the values from each row.
I am getting an error, the code is:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class TS1_TC2 {

WebDriver driver=null;

String btn1="html/body/form/div[1]/center/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input";
String table="html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table";

@BeforeTest
public void browserCheck()
{
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://demo.borland.com/gmopost/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


}
@Test
public void TS1_TC2()
{   
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(btn1)).click();
    //html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody
    //html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table
    WebElement table=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table"));
    List<WebElement> rows=table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100, 15);


    System.out.println(rows.size());
    for(int rownum=2;rownum<rows.size();rownum++)
    {
        List<WebElement> cols=rows.get(rownum).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        System.out.println(cols.size());
        for(int colnum=1;colnum<cols.size();colnum++)
        {
            //System.out.println(cols.get(colnum).getText());
            //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr["+rownum+"]/td["+colnum+"]")));
            System.out.println("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr["+rownum+"]/td["+colnum+"]");
            System.out.println(cols.get(colnum).findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr["+rownum+"]/td["+colnum+"]")).getText());
            System.out.println("--");
        }
            System.out.println();
    }


}
```

}

The Exception thrown is as follows:

```
FAILED: TS1_TC2
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]"}
Command duration or timeout: 20.08 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:55:11'
System info: host: 'Vihaan-PC', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 15f51aea-04cd-4ea4-bdae-0bdd47312bd7
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=29.0.1}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebElement.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:357)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:167)
    at TS1_TC2.TS1_TC2(TS1_TC2.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]"}
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:55:11'
System info: host: 'Vihaan-PC', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Vihaan/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7820392430389922124webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8904)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/Vihaan/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7820392430389922124webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:396)
```

Kindly help , because I see the the xpath from firepath is exactly the same as the xpath fetched in the for loop.

Thanks
rajee

Comment: What does the web page HTML look like?

Comment: Always use dynamic xpaths. never use absolute xpaths.

Answer (score 0):

try using

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr["+rownum+"]/td["+colnum+"]")).getText()`

instead of

`cols.get(colnum).findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr["+rownum+"]/td["+colnum+"]")).getText()`

It should work.

But I dont understand why you used the above line. The following code achieves the same thing.

```
WebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeTest
public void browserCheck() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://demo.borland.com/gmopost/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Test
public void TS1_TC2() {
    driver.findElement(By.name("bSubmit")).click();
    WebElement table = driver
            .findElement(By
                    .xpath("//form[@name='Items']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table"));

    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for (int rownum = 2; rownum < rows.size(); rownum++) {
        List<WebElement> cols = rows.get(rownum).findElements(
                By.tagName("td"));

        for (int colnum = 1; colnum < cols.size(); colnum++) {
            System.out.println(cols.get(colnum).getText());

        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

}
```

Let me know if this helps you.